# Не пойму, почему текст в поле input выводится по середине

Tags: css, input

[image: Тут я выделил номер]

Перед и после значения input есть пробелы и это значение находится посередине этих пробелов. Как то можно стилями это изменить?

Comment: добавьте html css

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте, что находится в базе. Или значение где-то копируется в строку заданной длины с выравниванием посередине.